# Cannot find module with tag 'cocos2dx-v2.2.2' in import path

Tags: android, python, eclipse, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I have problem when I import cocos2d-x 2.2.2 project I create it in `project_creator.py`
the problem is when I import the project to my workspace I have an error in android.mk

the error at line "$(call import-module,cocos2dx)"

when I try to build it I have error in console

```
"Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory: my_relative_path    
Android NDK: jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'cocos2dx' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:   "
```

I read many articles but no one can help me pleaaaase any help here ????

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `NDK_MODULE_PATH` variable in your environment setting and set its value to `cocos2d-x-2.2.2` path.

Comment: i do that but it not useful thanks anyway but any other solutions

Comment: If you have unzipped cocos2dx directly to the any drive `(e.g d:\cocos2d-x-2.2.2)`, then you have to add \ (back slash) to your path. In that case your `MDK_MODULE_PATH` will be `d:\cocos2d-x-2.2.2\` otherwise you don't need it.

Comment: i want to know something that if environment in eclipse setting or in windows variables ?????

Comment: You can use either one of them.